# Duplication of data when receiving a file through a socket

Tags: java, sockets, file-io

Sorry for the bad English, I used Google translate.

Working on an Application that needs to transfer a file over the network with the ability to resume, the program works, but why when you open a text file transmitted through nano seen that data is duplicated.

Server

```
OutputStream outToClient = socket.getOutputStream();

        File myfile = new File(filePath);
        System.out.println("файл " + myfile.toString());
        byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) myfile.length()];
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(myfile));

        BufferedOutputStream bost = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath+"111")));
        bost.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
        bis.skip(filePosition);
        bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
        bost.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
        outToClient.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);


        outToClient.flush();
        bis.close();
```

Client

```
 byte[] mybytearray = new byte[1024];
    fos = new FileOutputStream(fullPath, true);
    bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
    InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
    int bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);

    bos.write(mybytearray, 0, bytesRead);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    do {
        baos.write(mybytearray);
        bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray);

        if (bytesRead != -1)
            filePosition += bytesRead;
    } while (bytesRead != -1);

    bos.write(baos.toByteArray());
    bos.close();   socket.close();

    is.close();
    socket.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting some duplicate data because you are writing the same array contents to the output file twice before filling the array with new data.  You are not using the streams very well.  Try something more like this instead:

Server

```
OutputStream outToClient = socket.getOutputStream();

byte[] mybytearray = new byte[1024];
File myfile = new File(filePath);
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(myfile));
bis.skip(filePosition);
do {
    int bytesRead = bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
    if (bytesRead <= 0) {
        break;
    }
    outToClient.write(mybytearray, 0, bytesRead);
}
white (true);

outToClient.flush();
bis.close();
```

Client

```
byte[] mybytearray = new byte[1024];
//todo: seek the output file to the starting filePosition
//instead of just appending to the end of the file...
fos = new FileOutputStream(fullPath, true);
bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
do {
    int bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
    if (bytesRead <= 0) {
        break;
    }
    bos.write(mybytearray, 0, bytesRead);
    filePosition += bytesRead;
} while (true);

bos.close();
is.close();
socket.close();
```